# solve mismatch error for visual basic 6.0

Tags: arrays, vb6

When I run this code it show a dialog box that says 'Mismatch Type' at line `For i = 0 To UBound(arffArray)`. What is the problem with my code?

```
Public Function processFile()

    Dim i, j, posRelation, temp, att, data, flag
    Dim strRelation
    Dim strAtt
    Dim strData

    strRelation = "@relation"
    strAtt = "@attribute"
    strData = "@data"

    att = 0
    data = 0

    For i = 0 To UBound(arffArray)
        If (InStr(arffArray(i), strRelation)) Then
            temp = Replace(Mid(arffArray(i), 11, Len(arffArray(i))), "'", "")
            RelationName = temp
        ElseIf (InStr(arffArray(i), strAtt)) Then
            flag = parseAtt(att, arffArray(i))
            If (Not flag) Then
                processFile = flag
                Exit Function
            End If
            att = att + 1
        ElseIf (InStr(arffArray(i), strData)) Then
            data = readTheRest(i)
            i = UBound(arffArray) 'end the loop
            totalData = data
        End If
    Next

    'get the list of class name
    Dim tmpClassAttr
    tmpClassAttr = attArray(1, UBound(attArray, 2))

    For i = 0 To UBound(tmpClassAttr)
        ReDim Preserve classArray(i)
        classArray(i) = Trim(tmpClassAttr(i))
    Next

    processFile = True
End Function

'------------------------------------------------------------
'Function: parseAtt(num, attrData, ByVal m As MineKnow)
'require:
' >@num      -> current attribute counter
' >@attrData -> current attribute declaration
'Raises: error if reading non numeric data/attribute
'Return: boolean parseAtt TRUE/FALSE, TRUE if parse successfully or otherwise
'Effect: parsing file content to:
' > attributes
'------------------------------------------------------------
Private Function parseAtt(num, attrData)
    Dim temp, i, j, strAtt, temp2, pos, atVal
    ReDim Preserve attArray(2, num)

    'possible type of declarations
    '@attribute outlook {sunny, rainy, overcast}
    '@attribute outlook {sunny,rainy,overcast}
    'attribute pos = 12

    'get the attribute name first get the pos of "{"
    pos = InStr(1, attrData, "{", 1)

    If (pos = 0) Then
        error = "---->Nominal attribute only." & vbCrLf & "---->" & attrData
        parseAtt = False
        Exit Function
    Else
        strAtt = Trim(Mid(attrData, 12, pos - 12))
        atVal = Mid(attrData, pos + 1, Len(attrData) - (pos + 1))

        atVal = Replace(atVal, "'", "")
        atVal = Replace(atVal, "''", "")
        atVal = Replace(atVal, "}", "")
        atVal = Replace(atVal, " ", "")

        temp = Split(atVal, ",")

        attArray(0, num) = strAtt
        attArray(1, num) = temp
        parseAtt = True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: You **are** using *Option Explicit*, right?

Comment: yes. i'm using option explicit. and for arffArray still gt another part coding. but i didn't write it out.

Answer (score 4):

The biggest problem with your code is that you don't declare the type of your variables!!

Statements like

```
Dim i
```

will just declare the variable `i` as type `Variant`, which is definitely not what you want.

You actually want `i` to be declared as an `Integer`. You accomplish that by explicitly specifying the type at the point of declaration:

```
Dim i As Integer
```

Since the `For` loop is expecting an iterator index variable with type `Integer`, this should stop it from choking up that error.

Likewise, strings should always be declared explicitly as `String` types:

```
Dim strRelation As String
```

---

Note that when you declare multiple variables on a single line (which you probably shouldn't do, for clarity reasons), you need to make sure that you specify the type *for each variable*. It is not cumulative like other languages.

For example, this statement

```
Dim i, j, k As Integer
```

will declare *only* `k` as an `Integer`. `i` and `j` will be of type `Variant`, which is almost certainly (again) not what you wanted.

Instead, you need to write

```
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
```

---

Of course, in this particular case, since VB 6 allows you to use variables with a lower bound that is not 0, it's probably best to code the loop like this:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = LBound(arffArray) To UBound(arffArray)
    ' Do something with the array
Next i
```

Comment: All good advice but does not explain the error. Seems probable that arffArray is the cause. Maybe it is **not an array**?

Comment: I think what Cody is saying, is that since UBOUND returns an Integer, tonberry's code will (or at least has a better chance to) work once he DIMs i as an Integer.

Comment: but when i add Dim i As Integer also have same problem.

Comment: In these cases, the best thing to do is to provide a sample of code which can be compiled whilst still showing the error that you are getting. Take the code and chip it down to the bare essentials, paste into another instance of VB, then try to compile. Everytime it fails to build, add in the missing dependencies or change them to a dummy variable / routine. Repeat until you have a working example. By this point, you might have worked out the source of your problem all by yourself :-)

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 The problem is likely the definition of `arffArray`. Cody correctly pointed out that `i` is a `Variant`, which is bad practise. But it is perfectly legal to assign an `Integer` value to a `Variant`: it will not produce a *Type Mismatch* error. `tonberry` needs to post the definition `Dim` for `arffArray` and the code which gives `arffArray` a value. @tonberry you should follow Mark's advice in the comment just above. Make sure to use `Option Explicit`

Comment: Agreed with @MarkJ -- Variants can handle any data type so there's reason why an integer would cause a problem. The definition and use of arffArray needs to be explained.